# Dataframe columns cleaning

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean a number of columns in a dataset and try to iterate to different columns.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'A': [7.3\N\P,nan\T\Z,11.0\R\Z],
   'B': [nan\J\N, nan\A\G, 10.8\F\U], 
   'C': [12.4\A\I, 13.3\H\Z, 8.200000000000001\B\W]})

for name, values in df.iloc[:, 0:3].iteritems():
    def myreplace(s):
        for char in ['\A','\B','\C','\D','\E','\F','\G','\H','\I',
                '\J','\K','\L','\M','\\N','\O','\P','\Q','\R',
                 '\S','\T','\V','\W','\X','\Y','\Z','\\U']:
            s = s.map(lambda x: x.replace(char, ''))
        return s
    df = df.apply(myreplace)
```

I get the error: 'float' object has no attribue 'replace'

I could run this part on one column and it works, but I need to run it on several columns so this part does not work as I get an error that 'Dataframe'objec has no attribute 'str'

```
df_data.str.replace('[\\\|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z]', '')
```

I am really new to python pandas dataframe. Will appreciate the help

Comment: `[\\|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z]` is the same as `[\\A-Z]`

Answer (score 0):

Given, assuming the goal is to extract numbers from the strings:

```
          A         B                      C
0   7.3\N\P   nan\J\N               12.4\A\I
1   nan\T\Z   nan\A\G               13.3\H\Z
2  11.0\R\Z  10.8\F\U  8.200000000000001\B\W
```

Doing:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].str.extract('(\d*\.\d*)').astype(float)
```

Output:

```
      A     B     C
0   7.3   NaN  12.4
1   NaN   NaN  13.3
2  11.0  10.8   8.2
```

Comment: How can I iterate through all of the columns of a dataframe. I tried:                                        for col in df_data.iloc[:, 58:].iteritems():        loop through the dataframe from columns 58+
    df_data[col] = df_data[col].str.extract('(\d*\.\d*)').astype(float)                                                        I have the error typeEror invalid key

Comment: Stop trying to use loops on pandas dataframe items, that's not how they work. Use the vectorized functions.